# Auto-regressive model prediction decays to flatline

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, autoregressive-models

Apologies if this is a simple question/error, but when I try and predict a timeseries using statsmodels.tsa AR the prediction flatlines very quickly past the data I have. This doesn't depend on the order of the model or the length of the data used to fit the AR model.

What am I doing wrong?

```
from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AR
section1 = data[0:800]-np.mean(data[0:800])
plt.plot(section1)
```

[image]

```
x = AR(section1)
y = x.fit(5)
z = y.predict(10,1500)
plt.plot(z)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know how the regression model is attempting to fit your data? The data in your prediction from the range 0-800 looks like it has ben taken straight from your training set.

Comment: Yes, I think the first 800 is training set - In the docstring of Ar fit() "Returns in-sample and out-of-sample prediction." I wanted the out of sample to continue before 800 and not converge to the mean,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong. That's the behavior of a stationary ARMA process where predictions converge to the mean.

If you have fixed seasonality, then you could difference the time series at the seasonal lag, i.e. use a SARIMA, and the prediction would converge to a fixed seasonal structure.

If you have explanatory variables, then the prediction of a stationary ARMAX would converge to the mean given by the X variables.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So maybe I am using the AR model with the wrong idea? I thought to fit 2 models to 2 different time series, and get a set of AR coefficients for each model. I would then like to take a third time series and calculate the probability that the datapoints in it were generated by each of the two AR coeff sets. I would then be able to classify the third time series as being more "like" the first or second model, based on the probability. However, as an 'eyeball' test, I wanted to be able to generate 'fake' data from each AR model, to see they type of time series I was selecting for.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't fully understand you answer. - hence a roundabout reply containing what I do want.

Comment: If you want to simulate data from the ARMA process, then you need the noise or shocks to "bounce around" the time series. There is a generate_arma_sample function in statsmodels.tsa for this.

Comment: OK, I'll have a look at using an ARMA as apposed to AR to fit and then forecast- as I can't find a generate_ar_sample function. I wanted to use AR as the concept seems a lot simpler and is easier to understand! Apart from convenience of the simulating function in statsmodels, does ARMA offer significant advantages to modelling this type of data?

Comment: I didn't remember the name correctly. http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/tsa_arma_1.html  `arma_generate_sample` can be used to simulate a pure AR process if ma is set to [1], i.e. no lag coefficients in the polynomial.